# Please critique my question

Tags: discussion, questions, downvote-reason

Since joining SO, I've had a difficult time figuring out how to ask good questions (Yes, I've read the "*How to Ask Good Questions*" Article).  I want to ask good questions so I can contribute to the community and also so I don't get suspended from asking more questions (which has currently happened).

After I thought I'd figured out which questions will be downvoted and which ones upvoted, posted [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661599/javascript-error-uncaught-typeerror-ab-is-not-a-function)

**This question included:**

1. Desired behavior.
2. Current behavior.
3. What I've tried so far.
4. My code.
5. Proper grammar and formatting.

"Oh no!  Downvoting is happening again!"  I'm wondering now if my account is too far gone and if I'll ever be able to ask questions again.

**My two questions are:**

1. How can I improve upon this particular question.  Why did it get downvoted?
2. How can I know if my current account is fixable or if I should make a new one.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what should be done for that question... Not knowing anything about Telerik, I don't know if that's a common typo that would actually be useful to future users (or a duplicate), but that _does_ boil down to a typo question. We have a close reason specifically for typo questions, though if a typo question is a super common issue and will be helpful in the future, it's usually worth keeping around. (This is incredibly rare, to note.) Aside from it being a typo question, I'm not sure I see much else wrong with it personally.

Comment: It's always best to include text as text rather than a picture. I can't say that someone downvoted for that, but it is kind of annoying to have to open the image to read the error. Also, this kind of error is quite common, and therefore it might conceivably be downvoted for "lack of research".

Comment: More an SO issue than an issue with your question, but the text in the embedded picture is illegible on the screen of my laptop

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  Yes, I knew that image of the error would count against me.  I thought it'd be easier to look at than pasting the text in.

Comment: General consensus, seems like the question in question isn't a complete disaster.  I messed up by using an image rather than pasting text.  Somehow I don't think that's the reason for the downvoting.

Comment: It looks like you're asking others to debug your code for you. Did you debug?  What did you find?  And where the heck is `SetDateSession()`?  Is that where the error is being thrown?  Your question is formatted perfectly, you've got lots of good info in there, but how can anybody answer it?

Comment: Oh, and images of errors really is an offensive thing.  Whenever I see error details in a question, I often select the relevant bits and search for it.  **Lots** of people do this.  If you post an image of an error, I have to *transcribe it*.  And if I mess something up doing so, I don't get relevant hits.  So whenever I see this now I punch a baby.

Comment: @Will Please understand.  The image I posted was simply for visual reference of how the error looked in the console.  The original error message was in text, in another part of the post.  Please explain why this is offensive.

Comment: @Will I've taken your advice and updated the question to reflect your suggested changes.  Feel free to check it out.

Comment: The offensive part may be a little overblown, but the important bit is "If you post an image of an error, I have to transcribe it." I'm already here volunteering, for free, my time to help you with your problem.  If you do things *on purpose* that force me to waste my time, that's going to piss me off.  I'm helping you, why are you effing with me?  I know it takes time to cull error messages for privileged info, to paste it and format it nicely in the question, but that's on you.  Anyhow, I understand what you meant by it being a throwaway and (possibly) not necessary to answer the question.

Comment: The ironic thing about your problem, is that you've gotten seven up votes on _this_ question. If only you could transfer upvotes from MSO to SO.

Comment: Here is one of the reasons questions are (or should be) closed which I think is a fitting description of your question: *This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.*